# how much time it will take to fully charge a 48 V 35 Amp hr battery using a 100 V DC dynamo running at an average speed of 20 km/hr

Tags: batteries, charging

The above mentioned dynamo is being used in an e bike.
i have tried to go through many sites but didn't get a proper answer.

Comment: the dynamo is 100 V DC

Comment: How long does it take to fill a 200 gallon bathtub with a bucket?  Unless you tell us how big the bucket is and the rate of fill etc. there's no way to know.  We need the specs on the generator, the conversion from 20km/hr to shaft speed (gear ratio, etc.) and the method of controlling the current into the battery. (How much current are you providing the battery at 20km/hr or how much power is the dynamo putting out.)

Comment: Do you have infinite torque? If so, it should be possible to charge your battery instantly.

Comment: Info missing, need to know the specifications of the dynamo, such as current.

Comment: Voting to close this old question which was abandoned without the necessary information to make it answerable ever being provided.

Answer (score 2):

Typical bike dynamo has 6W nominal power.

48V 35Ah battery has 1680Wh (watt hours). For normal bike dynamo that would be

1680Wh/6W = 280h

However if you use bigger dynamo - wikipedia says:

> A trained cyclist can produce about 400 watts of mechanical power for an hour or more, but adults of good average fitness average between 50 and 150 watts for an hour of vigorous exercise. A healthy well-fed laborer over the course of an 8-hour day can sustain an average output of about 75 watts.[1] The yield of electric power is decreased by the efficiency of the human-powered generator.

So, trained cyclist:

1680Wh / 400W = ~4h

Healthy well-fed laborer:

1680Wh / 75W = 22,4h

Notice, thats just a generator powered by human legs, not bike that moves and charges battery at the same time. There are also power losses and limited battery efficiency. You may need to add about 50% mechanical energy for power losses on dynamo, charging circuit and battery chemical/thermal losses.